# Optimization of image reading and processing functions

Tags: python, image, optimization, microcontroller

I have a function that reads images in specific directories, but it is very slow, it takes more than minutes for it to read all the images I want, how can I optimize it?

```
def process_images_optimized(self, image_paths, labels):
        images = [self.load_and_resize_image(img_path) for img_path in image_paths]
        return images, np.array(labels)

def load_and_resize_image(self, img_path):
        with Image.open(img_path) as img:
            img = img.resize((self.image_size[1], self.image_size[0]))
            img_array = np.array(img) / 255.0
        return img_array
```

I would like an explanation of how I can improve the functions I created to perform the same operation in the shortest possible time.

Comment: buy faster computer. Or run on servers like `Google Colab` - they may work faster than your computer.

Comment: you may try to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run many  functions at the same time. There are other (external) modules for subprocessing which can make it simpler - like [joblib](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), `ray`

Comment: maybe you should first resize all images using tools create with C/C++ - like `imagemagick` - and later you will have less work in Python. But first you should check if problem is time of resizing or time of reading to memory.

Comment: If you cannot change the operation, multiprocessing would be the first thing to try. If you are allowed to do so, you can also try saving the resized image as a binary file (e.g. npy). Note that simply changing png to jpg will significantly reduce the decoding load.

Comment: @furas I'm setting up a function to work with microcontrolled systems, it's not simply buying a new computer or running it somewhere else, otherwise I would have done it already.

Comment: maybe if you would mention `microcontroller` in question (not in comments) then you would get better solutions from other people. It may shows how important is to show all details in question.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear with this, but it is for microcontrollers that I need it, that is, I need to work in an extremely limited environment, so I adhered to your suggestion and included the tag in the question @furas.

Comment: Not sure how you imagine we can help. You give no indication of your operating system, your CPU, your RAM or what type of disk you use. There's no indication what format the images are stored in, nor of their original nor intended size. No indication of how many images you have, nor why you want them all stored in RAM at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really test this with your code since you didn't provide a working copy, but since you're IO-bound, something like this will most likely help you:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as TPE 
from os import cpu_count
import numpy as np

class ImageProcessing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tpe = TPE(max_workers=cpu_count())

    def process_images_optimized(self, n):
        return list(self.tpe.map(self.load_and_resize_image, [(5,5)]*10))

    def load_and_resize_image(self,size):
        return np.random.random(size)
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.tpe.shutdown(cancel_futures=True)

ip = ImageProcessing()
images = ip.process_images_optimized(10)
```

Just replace the fake image generation functions with your file reading example. If the `process_images_optimized` function is called only once, you should use `with TPE(max_workers=cpu_count()) as tpe:` instead of the method I have shown, but if it's called multiple times then keeping the pool alive makes more sense.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand how your code would be implemented together with mine. The idea of this code is that you use the "process_images_optimized" function to load a directory that has other folders inside, within each of these subfolders, you have a class of images.

Comment: read up on thread pool executor and map, then you'll understand how it works and how to "merge" this example with your code

Comment: The main idea is that I would like to use a reading function like the one available in tensorflow, but this function is not implemented in several versions for microcontrollers. Therefore, I wanted to develop my own to do this, but I cannot reach a satisfactory performance. The function I'm referring to would be tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory.

Comment: a microcontroller will not be able to do image processing at all, even "powerful" SBCs like the Pi family struggle to keep up with 10 FPS. The Nvidia Jetson series has GPUs that make it possible to do what you want in a robotics / embedded application. You're massively over estimating the IO bandwidth of an MCU and what is capable of

Comment: Sorry, but I'm the one who thinks you're underestimating the computational power of these cards. I've already done three projects using this type of methodology, running image processing almost in real time on this type of cards, including with artificial intelligence with complex architectures.

Comment: Therefore, I can say with certainty, although a board like Jeston allows the execution of more robust models, I guarantee that all this is not needed to run a convolutional neural network that allows application using edge computing. And I also say one thing, if it runs at 10 fps, why not take photos and work with the image taken? And does 10 fps not really meet your demand? I know it sounds a bit crazy, but I can say that with photos taken almost in real time it can be applied to countless projects.

Comment: If you're happy with "almost real time" and 10 fps, then sure, but I come from a background where "image processing" and "CNNs" mean processing 1080P 60FPS footage as a minimum requirement, which only leaves FPGAs and GPUs on the table, not an MCU.